# Evaluating an expression using Euler's theorem for Homogeneous Functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> If $u=\arcsin\left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}\right)$. Prove that:
> $$x^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+2xy\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x\partial y}+y^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=\frac{-\sin(u)\cos(2u)}{4\cos^3(u)}$$

*Here is what I have thus far:*

A simple application of Euler's theorem for Homogeneous Functions yields the following equality.
$$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{1}{2}\tan(u)$$
It can be noted that:
$$\begin{aligned}
x^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+2xy\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}+y^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}&= \left[x\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right]^{2} \\ 
&= x^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+y^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}+xy\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x\partial y}+yx\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y\partial x} \\ 
&= x^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+y^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}+2xy\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}
\end{aligned}$$
But I am unsure of how to convert $\frac{1}{2}\tan(u)$ into a function which represents $x,y$ homogeneously. Any ideas on how to proceed? Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function
$ f(x,y) 
= \sin u(x,y)
= \frac{x+y}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}
$
is homogeneous with degree $n=1/2$ since
$$ f(tx,ty)=t^{1/2} f(x,y)$$

Euler's homogeneous function theorem gives two relations
$$
x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+
y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=
n f \tag{1}
$$
and
$$
x^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+y^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+2xy\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} 
=  n(n-1) f \tag{2}
$$

Using chain rule, it is easy to see that
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
=
\cos u 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
,
\frac{{\partial ^2 f}}{{\partial x^2 }} 
=
\cos u
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
-
\sin u 
\left(
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
\right)^2 
$$

Plugging these partial derivatives into (1) yield the relation
$$
a=x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+
y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
=\frac{1}{2} \tan u
$$

Plugging these partial derivatives into (2) yield the relation
$$
b \cos u
- a^2 \sin u 
=
-\frac{1}{4} \sin u
$$
where
$$
b =
x^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+ y^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}+ 2xy\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}
$$
is the LHS of your problem.

Rearranging terms and using the value of $a$ yields
\begin{eqnarray*}
b \cos u
&=&
\frac{\sin u}{4}
\left[
\frac{\sin^2 u}{\cos^2 u}
-1
\right]
=
\frac{\sin u}{4}
\left[
\frac{\sin^2 u-\cos^2 u}{\cos^2 u}
\right]
=
-
\frac{\sin u}{4}
\left[
\frac{\sin 2u}{\cos^2 u}
\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
and finally $b$.